# Display of digits from 1 to 100 in c# such that each line ends with a modulus of 10

Tags: c#

I am a beginner learning c#, I have this code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int a = 0;
    while (a < 100)
    {
        a = a + 1;
        if ((a % 10) == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }
        else
        {               
            Console.Write(a);
            Console.Write(",");  
        }                
    }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way of writing this code? I feel there might be a better way of doing this in c#. This is my very first code. I will appreciate a response. Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a review and should thus go to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow. Although I wrote you an answer, I agree with HimBromBeere to close this question. Check out the codereview site it's worth it when you want to improve working code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the short version would look like this:

```
int stepSize = 10;

for (int i = 1; i < 100; i+=stepSize )
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(i, stepSize)));
}
```

Explanation:

You walk in steps of 10 through your for-loop. at each step the 
 [Enumerable.Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.110).aspx) method creates an array which holds numbers enumerated from a start value (`i`) until the count value (`10`).

The [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) method takes each element of this array and combines them into a string separated by a `,`

Since it looks like homework:

You should research how to use[String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx). This way you could arrange elements in one line at certain positions.

For iterations with a counter variable a for-loop is preferable, because it is exactly made for it with a clearly readable head signature.

You actually wrote a very readable code, which in my opinion is efficient. A shortening of codelines does not make it necessarily more efficient or faster or more readable. Sometimes the only advantage is that it looks a little more elegant ;) that's all

**EDIT:**

You can even get it down to one line:

```
Console.WriteLine(Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => String.Join(",", Enumerable.Range(x * 10 + 1, 10))));
```

it is short, but it is horrible to read and understand :)

Answer (score 3):

First step would be using a foor loop instead.

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
{
    if ((i % 10) == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write(i);
        Console.Write(",");  
    }
}
```

You could replace

```
Console.Write(i);
Console.Write(",");
```

with

```
Console.Write(string.Format("{0},", i));
```

or even better with

```
Console.Write($"{i},");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just yet another approach

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    Console.Write(i);
    Console.Write(i % 10 == 0 ? Environment.NewLine : ",");
}
```

Comment: I guess for a beginner this line: `i % 10 == 0 ? Environment.NewLine : ","` really is in need of a few lines of explanation...

Comment: @MongZhu OP could ask me if it really needed and I will do my best in that case :)